# How to count values in pattern in Robot Framework

Tags: regex, robotframework

I would like to know how to count values into pattern.

```
${pattern}=  (422030B|423020B|420125B|425502B|GS550224|426655B)
 
${selected_values}= (422030B, 420125B, 999999)
```

my expected results are 2 values: 422030B, 420125B.

I'm using search function but it return only first value:

```
${result}   Evaluate   re.search(r'(${pattern})','''${selected_values}''').group(0)  re
```

Please help me find where the problem is.

Comment: Check out the String library. There is a keyword that can be used for this.

Comment: Are pattern and selected_values lists? If yes, then it's trivial to get the counts; if not - transform them to lists :)

Answer (score 1):

The example you have, cannot give you two results, since you specificly ask only for group(0). But you can use findall and this will give you the list of two matches you are looking for.
Here is the code, in the result you will have list with the two matches.

```
*** Variables ***
${pattern}    (422030B|423020B|420125B|425502B|GS550224|426655B)
 
${selected_values}    (422030B, 420125B, 999999)

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    ${result}   Evaluate   re.findall(r'(${pattern})','''${selected_values}''')    re
    Log    ${result}
```

here is [findall.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)
Similar result will be produced if you use groups() method insted of group()

```
${result}   Evaluate   re.search(r'(${pattern})','''${selected_values}''').groups()    re
Log    ${result}
```